# Coefficients estimated using fit.variogram don't match the plot with the model fit (gstat R package)

Tags: r, gstat, geostatistics

I'm fitting an exponential model to an empirical semivariogram using the package gstat.
My dataset (data) has latitude and longitude values in decimal degrees.
The range estimated using `fit.variogram()` doesn't match the range that I'd expect by looking at the plot of the model. See code and figures below.

This is the output from `fit.variogram()`:

```
   model    psill    range
1   Nug 26.66719  0.00000
2   Exp 26.26643 25.76976
```

From here I would expect the range corresponding to a sill of ~53 (26.66719+26.26643) to be 25.76976. However, when looking at the plot the range corresponding to a sill of ~53 is >60 km.
[image: plot with fitted model]

```
library(gstat)  
library(sp)

coordinates(data)= ~ longitude+latitude
proj4string(data)=CRS("+longlat")
TheVariogram=variogram(Svmean~1, data=data, cutoff=90)
plot(TheVariogram) #to get seed parameters
lzn.fit <- fit.variogram(TheVariogram, model = vgm(psill=60, model="Exp", nugget=20, range=70),fit.method=6)
plot(TheVariogram, pl=F, model=lzn.fit, xlab="Distance (km)", ylab=expression(Semivariance (dB^2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range reported is the range parameter a in the model exp(-h/a), and not the value at which the exponential model reaches 95% of its (partial) sill. To get that latter value, multiply by (approximately) 3.

Comment: Although this answers the question (and is supported in the user manual at https://www.gstat.org/gstat.pdf), it would be interesting to know *why* range works this way in gstat.

"Exp(), Gau() and Bes() models reach their sill asymptotically (as h → ∞).
The ‘effective range’, is the distance where the variogram reaches 95% of its
maximum, and this is 3a for Exp(a), √3a for Gau(a) and 4a for Bes(a)"